# Asp.net MVC 3 Membership.UpdateUser Appears To Do Nothing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I built a module into my MVC site that allows administrators to create, modify and delete website users. However, I can not seem to update user information via the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    try
    {
      //CHANGE EXISTING USER
      MembershipUser siteUser = Membership.GetUser(user.Username);
      siteUser.Email = user.Email;
      siteUser.IsApproved = true;
      siteUser.Comment = "User Update on " + DateTime.UtcNow;
      siteUser.UnlockUser();
      Membership.UpdateUser(siteUser);
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password))
      {
        siteUser.ChangePassword(siteUser.GetPassword(), user.Password);
      }
      unitOfWork.UsersRepository.Update(user);
      unitOfWork.Save();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
      // CODE REMOVED FOR BREVITY
    }
  }
  return View(user);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After further testing, it would appear that one line was causing the user information to reset.

```
siteUser.UnlockUser();
```

This line can not be called prior to saving user alterations via `Membership.UpdateUser()` or the changes will be lost. Hopefully this saves somebody some head scratching.